# Office Web Add-In dynamically adding buttons

Tags: office-js, word-web-addins

I've just started to lean about Web Add-ins for Microsoft Word. My Add-in is built in Visual Studio 2017 and is a C# app.  All of the examples I've seen so far hook up event handlers to buttons in the `Office.initialize` function in the accompanying JS.

```js
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        app.initialize();

        // Add event handler to button click event for the 'get-translation' button.
        $('#MyButton').click(get-translation);
    });
};
```

When initially loaded, I don't know all of the buttons I want to display to the user as they will be dynamically created based upon user selections in various combo boxes.  How can I hook my events for newly created buttons as `Office.initialize` is only run when the page is initially loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to wire the `.click` event in `Office.initialize`, it is just the logical place to do it when you have static buttons to wire up. You can just as easily wire up the `.click` when you add the buttons to the DOM.